Conditional formatting if a cell is a duplicate value
Here is what I've got and here is the outcome I want where I was initially using really long and unnecessarily complex formulas to do so using ad-hoc error-states that no longer work with the latest version of Google Sheets, but now am thinking, as per some guidance on a different question, that I really actually want conditional formatting similar to this.
What I want, however, is the text to become transparent when there's a duplicate, but only for the duplicates, not the original, so the first change in a column becomes visible, then if it's repeated down throughout the cells, it becomes transparent until there's a change in value.
I'm kind of stumped on this one, and although my logic is sound, I haven't used conditional formatting before, before I previously used formulas that returned a blank string if it were a duplicate, such as LOOKUP(2,1/(E:E<>"" as part of the formula, but Google Sheets returns a different kind of error state nowadays, so although this direct formula approach worked years ago, it no longer does.
So, how do I make the text transparent, but only for consecutive duplicates? (not just any duplicate in the column) - if you see  it sometimes blanks out values where it shouldn't.

Try this to apply conditional formatting to consecutive duplicates that are also not blanks.
Select 'Apply to range' as B2:B
=AND($B1=$B2,$B2<>"")


THAT WORKED! I'VE BEEN TRYING TO GET THIS WORKING FOR DAYS!!
this is just a bonus question, and i understand it's probably unnecessary, but is there a way to choose a transparent colour instead of selecting an actual colour?

Hm, I don't think that's possible but I'll need to look around for a bit and get back to you.

it may be possible to select an alpha variant by modifying the asm in excel, but i don't think it's possible in google sheets, as it's web-based (even though browsers support transparent colours) so don't worry too much if you can't - i don't expect it to be possible, anymore

i've run into a problem where if the same value is repeated throughout anywhere in the column, it simply won't show up - i need it to repeat a value, but only when it's not consecutively

I've updated the answer to satisfy the edits you applied to the question.

that doesn't seem to work, it just rearranged some blank cells where they should not be blank

Did you set the range of the conditional formatting rule as it explains in the answer? It should be working. Take a look at this example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Na1L8Wx0g6LJW-bTXdBb_DIn9NfT0qtSmCnN0Q2EkvU/

yes, but try repeating some values in the left column, it sometimes applies the formatting when it shouldn't

Do you still have the original conditional formatting rule on the range as well? Remove that and it should be fine. If that still isn't working for you, share a sheet with me and I can debug for you.

yes, sorry, i thought you meant to include the original conditional formatting, too - can you update the answer to remove that? - it works 100% of the time, now. thanks!
